# Wordpress auto generates small medium and large of an image on upload, how can we guess their links?

Tags: permalinks, uploads, post-thumbnails, media-library, core-modifications

WordPress out of the box has an **integrated image sizes system**, which creates files ( thumbnail, S, M, L) but in the media library, it only shows **one original file size** link.

Let's say, I **upload** a file named pretty-cat.jpg and I **want** to use a **medium-size image** which is around 700px and I know WordPress has it in its **images folder** but for that, I have to **navigate** to that folder to find the name of the file.

There should be an **option** to copy a **medium image** link in the **media library** or there should be **some logic** attached to it like if I **want** a **medium-size** Image I would simply type **/pretty-cat-medium.jpg**.

Comment: In what context do you need to guess the URL? There are functions for getting the correct URL, so guessing shouldn’t be required.

Comment: Do you mean like these functions, [wp_get_attachment_image()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

Comment: On the Media Library page when you select a single image, on the right panel, under File URL: section, there should be Small, Medium, Large image sizes URL section, please refer to this image https://i.imgur.com/3PSqzu3.png
As you can see in the image, how can we achieve this? This feature should be great for bloggers.